# jQuery Automated Anchor Navigation - Adding Pixel Offset

Tags: jquery, css, automation, anchor

Live page: http://wlvrtn.com/sites/nms/page.php

I've added some jQuery (thanks to help from StackOverflow) to automate the destination of my chapter links, such that the Chapter Three link will direct to the third Chapter (article) on the page.

As you can see from the live page, my sticky navbars get in the way of the beginning of each chapter. **I'd like to offset each jquery anchor by 200px vertically so that the start of each chapter displays properly.**

HTML - Chapters Nav:

```
<nav id="chapters">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Chapter One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Chapter Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Chapter Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

HTML - Article:

```
<article class="clearfix">  
    <h1>Chapter One</h1>
    ...
</article>
```

jQuery:

```
// Chapters - find the nav & headers
var nav = $('#chapters li a'),
    articles = $('#main article > h1');

// Chapters - now assign an id/href to each
nav.each(function (i) {
    nav.eq(i).attr('href', '#article-' + i);
    articles[i].id = 'article-' + i;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by rearranging the elements:

```
<h1>Chapter One<a id="article-0" style="position: relative; top: -200px;">&nbsp;</a></h1>
```

Here the anchor that you're linking to is not the `h1` but a 'stub' element inside the `h1` that's offset by a few pixels.

Obviously CSS classes would be a bit better:

```
.v-offset { 
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;
}

...

<h1>Chapter One<a id="article-0" class="v-offset">&nbsp;</a></h1>
```

You can use jQuery's [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method to write the anchors in dynamically

```
nav.each(function (i, ele) {
    $(ele).attr('href', '#article-' + i); // $(ele) == $nav.eq(i)
    $(articles[i]).append('<a id="article-' + i + '" class="v-offset">&nbsp;</a>');
});
```

Comment: This is a great start, although I'm looking to do this without specifying an id for articles, as they'll be being generated by a client via CMS later on.

Comment: Could I use append() to apply the "article-0" and "v-offset" directly to the h1?

Comment: Probably not. You need to position the `#article-0` anchor relative to the `h1`.

Comment: @pianofighter Sorry I didn't read your jQuery closely enough. I've updated my answer to something that should work out better for you.

Comment: I've tried your updated code, but haven't got it working yet. Probably a noob jQuery mistake. Would you take a quick look?
Page: http://wlvrtn.com/sites/nms/page.php
JS: http://wlvrtn.com/sites/nms/_/js/functions.js

Comment: @pianofighter your functions.js has two `nav.each(...)` loops. Replace your original loop with mine.

Answer (score 0):

Add either **margin-left:200px** or **padding-left:200px**  to the item that you want indented.

Comment: That's not what OP wants. The way I read the question the scroll position should offset by 200px so the heading bar doesn't obscure the content after you click the link

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply shift the listed text, you can do something like this as well:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
  ul{
        margin-left:200px;
    }
```

*OR*

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li{
    text-indent:200px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: I may have worded my question improperly. I've edited it to clarify that I'm looking for the article anchors to be shifted 200px vertically. Take a look at http://wlvrtn.com/sites/nms/page.php and you'll see what I mean.